# How do test in Django

Tags: python, django, django-testing

I'm trying to do my first tests on Django and I don't know do it or after reading the docs (where it explains a very easy test) I still don't know how do it.

I'm trying to do a test that goes to "login" url and makes the login, and after a succesfull login redirects to the authorized page.

```
from unittest import TestCase

from django.test.client import Client


class Test(TestCase):
    def testLogin(self):
        client = Client()
        headers = {'X-OpenAM-Username': 'user', 'X-OpenAM-Password': 'password', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        data = {}
        response = client.post('/login/', headers=headers, data=data, secure=False)
        assert(response.status_code == 200)
```

And the test success, but I don't know if it's beacuse the 200 of loading "/login/" or because the test do the login and after redirect get the 200 code.

How can I check on the test that after the login the url redirected it's the correct? There is a plugin or something that helps with the test? Or where I can find a good tutorial to test my views and the model?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Why don't you follow [Django doct on testing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/)?

Comment: I've tried to follow the doc's tutorial but I get errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To properly test redirects, use the [follow](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.post) parameter

> If you set follow to True the client will follow any redirects and a
>   redirect_chain attribute will be set in the response object containing
>   tuples of the intermediate urls and status codes.

Then your code is as simple as

from django.test import TestCase

```
class Test(TestCase):
    def test_login(self):
        client = Client()
        headers = {'X-OpenAM-Username': 'user', 'X-OpenAM-Password': 'password', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        data = {}
        response = client.post('/login/', headers=headers, data=data, secure=False)
        self.assertRedirects(response,'/destination/',302,200)
```

Note that it's `self.assertRedirects` rather than `assert` or `assertRedirects`

Also note that the above test will most likely fail because you are posting an empty dictionary as the form data. Django form views do not redirect when the form is invalid and an empty form will probably be invalid here.

Comment: Ah, ok thanks. I'm at work now, I will try later! I send data={} beacause I don't login with Django, I delegate the login on an IDP (OpenAM) and on the code I use the same format and works, so in the test it should work too :/

Comment: Works, only one more question. Why I get "AssertionError: Response didn't redirect as expected: Response code was 200 (expected 302)" On the code I use "return HttpResponseRedirect('/loggedin')". It's right?

Comment: I don't know why, but debuggin I see that "redirect_chain" it's empty. I'm trying the Docs examples adapted to my code but I'm getting an empty list on the "redirect_chain"....

Comment: sorry for the delay, that means your view isn't redirecting as you expected, probably the situation I mentioned : the form isn't being validated properly.

Comment: No problem! I will check if it's beacuse the form fails, but I don't know why If on the code and using the website as normal it works perfectly. Maybe I should configure something or do the test in other way. Thanks for your hep!

Comment: glad to have helped

Answer (score 1):

Django have plenty of tools for testing. For this task, you should use test case class from Django, for example `django.test.TestCase`.
Then you can use method `assertRedirects()` and it will check where you've been redirected and with which code. You can find any info you need [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/tools/).
I've tried to write the code for your task:

```
from django.test import TestCase

class Test(TestCase):
    def test_login(self):
        data = {'X-OpenAM-Username': 'user', 'X-OpenAM-Password': 'password'}
        response = client.post('/login/', data=data, content_type='application/json', secure=false)
        assertRedirects(response, '/expected_url/', 200)
```

Then you can use `python3 manage.py test` to run all tests.

Comment: Hi, I've tried to do this before ask this question, but I get " in assertRedirects url = response.url AttributeError: 'HttpResponse' object has no attribute 'url' " all the time.